# using SLAPI to create roles

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to `setup SAML SSO with SoftLayer, using ADFS`.

According to http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/setup-identity-federation-scenarios i should create roles within SL using SL API as I want to use scenario 2.

Anybody know how to create roles and how to match it with my ADFS ?

I already have the SAML configured on the SL side, and on my ADFS I have imported the XML.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take some time to follow the [Stack Overflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Also provide us the relevant code you wrote for your question (You can also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The creation of roles is new and it is available only for API, here some examples to create the roles and assing tthem the permissions these are the steps you need to follow:

1.-Create Role
2.-Create a group
3.-Assing actions to the Group
4.-Link the group to the role

Here an RESTful example to create the role:

```
POST https://$USER:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_User_Permission_Role/createObject

payload:
{
    "parameters":[ {
        "name": "myName",
        "description": "test"
    }]
}
```

Create Group:

```
POST https://$USER:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_User_Permission_Group/createObject

payload:
{
    "parameters": [
        {"name": "myGroup",
         "description": "mydescription"    
        }
        ]
}
```

List all the actions or permissions available for a group

```
GET https://$USER:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_User_Permission_Action/getAllObjects
```

The request above will return the actions and you need to write down the ids of the permissions that you want and then assing them to the group

Assing actions to the group:

```
POST https://$USER:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_User_Permission_Group/$GROUPID/addBulkActions

payload:
{
    "parameters":[
          [
              {"id":1},
              {"id":2}
          ]
        ]
}
```

Link the group to the role:

```
POST https://$USER:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_User_Permission_Role/$ROLEID/linkGroup

PAYLOAD:
{
    "parameters": [
        {"id":  1111  -> the id of your goup
        }
        ]
}
```

Then you can add users to you role useing the method addUsers

See documetation http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_User_Permission_Role

Regards

Comment: So, you are saying that Role is kinda like generic entity that can be compared to user. so i won't have an actual user, but my SAML response from my adfs would state that my userid X (authenticated within my own corporate ADFS) is assigned Role Y. SoftLayer side would "recognize" Role Y and not specific user X, and my permission would be the permissions of Role Y.

Comment: the role has users you have to add the users that you want to that role, the role is just a way to manage the permissions an user can have several roles. but in the scenario that you want to deploy it says that the users only exists in the IdP and only the name of the roles in both sides needs to be the same I never performed that setup but I guess that the role in softlayer is only the way to assing the permissions in softlayer to your user in IdP. Please mark this answer as the correct becasuse you asked how to create the roles by API and I anwered that